# How to access list data in an app web from another app web

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, online

I understand how to access app web(SharePoint hosted app) list data from host web, or the other way(app web -> host web). However, is there a way to access another app web's data from an app web?

For example:
SharePoint hosted app 1
https://xxxxxxx-mysite.sharepoint.com/Site1/App1
to another
SharePoint hosted app 2
https://yyyyyyy-mysite.sharepoint.com/Site1/App2/_api/web....

Provided, of course, that they are on the same site.